# Test In-App Purchase without uploading a screenshot to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

The status of my In-App Purchase product is

> Waiting for Screenshot

How can I test it to upload the screenshot?

Right now I cannot get any products. Here is my code:

```
public func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        // ...
        let products = response.products
       // ...
}
```

`products` has 0 element.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I found out that my product ID ends up in `response.invalidProductIdentifiers` and not in `response.products`
I have also uploaded the screenshot as suggested in answers, what could go wrong ?

Comment: did u create IAP products in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload a screenshot in order for Apple to review your IAP.

Take a screenshot of the button that triggers the IAP (or anything related to your IAP).

Then test it.

Comment: You can test the IAP prior to approval but the screenshot is required for testing.

Comment: Thank you too, Iĺl try it and let you know as wel

Comment: @DanielStorm You just wrote an 
antinomic sentence.

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like the IAP has to be approved first. The IAP does not get reviewed and approved until you submit it with your application.

Comment: @DanielStorm Now this makes sense :D Thank you for pointing this out, I didn't realise I had written that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually test the in-app purchasing in the sandbox environment, basically you'll need to set up an test user account in your iTunesConnect. In sandbox mode you able to test and get alert like below image

[image]

And the sandbox image to IAP product in iTunes `Waiting for Screenshot`

Check the apple documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

You'll be able to find all the information related to In-App Purchasing, including sandbox testing.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted but in the link Bala provides Apple states that you can add products in iTunes Connect and leave them in the 'Waiting for Screenshot' state and then test them in the Sandbox.